# Why is my Twilio nodejs transcribing attempt calling the client twice?

Tags: node.js, twilio

It is calling the client twice and making 1 37 second (in twilio dashboard) phonecall with two transcripts one 22 seconds long the other 5 seconds long, anyone have any ideas?
The phonecall when I make a straight phonecall and record lasts 19 seconds. Thats what my transcript should be 19 seconds longs. Its looping around somewhere.

I used real credentials and real phone numbers.

```
var twilio = require('twilio');
var client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);


const VoiceResponse = require('twilio').twiml.VoiceResponse;

client.calls.create({
  url: 'http://107.170.228.177:80/sendT',
  to: '+17000000',
  from: '+10000000'

})

app.post('/sendT', urlencodedParser, function(req, res) {
  console.log('made to send t')

  const rt = new VoiceResponse();
  rt.record({
    transcribe: true,
    transcribeCallback: '/rT'
  });
  res.status(200);
  res.send(rt.toString());
  console.log('RT string' + rt.toString());
})

app.post('/rT', urlencodedParser, function(req, res) {
  console.log('made to receiveT post');
  var ttemp = req['body'].TranscriptionText;
  console.log('transcription text ' + ttemp);
  var masterFile = __dirname + "/master/t.json";
  fs.writeFile(masterFile, ttemp, function(err) {}) //
  res.status(200);
  res.send();
});
```

NodeJS output

```
RT string<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Response><Record transcribe="true" transcribeCallback="/rT"/></Response>
made to send t
RT string<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Response><Record transcribe="true" transcribeCallback="/rT"/></Response>
made to send t
RT string<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Response><Record transcribe="true" transcribeCallback="/rT"/></Response>
made to receiveT post
*call transcript*
made to receiveT post
*call transcript*
```

Comment: Are you `require`ing this file twice?

Comment: No. I added some If statements around and basically made some on off switches so there was no way the recording or transcribing could be run twice. I would like to do it the right way instead of a hacky way. But it does work now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

What is happening here is very specific to the [`<Record>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record) TwiML that you are using.

When the recording is finished being made, Twilio will make an HTTP request to the [`action` attribute that you set on the `<Record>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record#attributes-action) to see what to do with the call now. In the case of no `action` attribute, Twilio will make that request to the current document URL, that is your `/sendT` endpoint in this case.

This is what it causing the loop, the `<Record>` then appears again to Twilio and times out after 5 seconds, at which point the call is decided to be over. Now you get two recordings, including 5 seconds of silence.

To fix this, you should either add an `action` attribute that points to an endpoint that just returns the TwiML to [`<Hangup/>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/hangup).

```
app.post('/sendT', urlencodedParser, function(req, res) {    
  const rt = new VoiceResponse();
  rt.record({
    transcribe: true,
    transcribeCallback: '/rT',
    action: '/hangup'
  });
  res.status(200);
  res.send(rt.toString());
})

app.post('/hangup', function(req, res) {
  const hangup = new VoiceResponse();
  hangup.hangup();
  res.status(200);
  res.send(hangup);
})
```

Or, you can keep no `action` URL and just check the request to see if it has already made a recording and hang up conditionally based on that.

```
app.post('/sendT', urlencodedParser, function(req, res) {    
  const rt = new VoiceResponse();
  if (typeof req.body.RecordingUrl !== 'undefined') {
    rt.hangup();
  } else {
    rt.record({
      transcribe: true,
      transcribeCallback: '/rT',
      action: '/hangup'
    });
  }
  res.status(200);
  res.send(rt.toString());
})
```

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: I added conditional statements to fix it but your answer is correct and I will fix my code. Thankyou.

Comment: Glad to hear this is sorted!

Comment: Hopefully this will help someone else as well, because I read that documentation many times. Where is this in the documentation? Maybe I just completely missed it. If you could point me to the link I would appreciate it.

Comment: Right here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record#attributes-action